# Strange pattern in rounding errors?

Tags: st.statistics, special-functions

This will look at first like a posting about trigonometry, then maybe about statistics, then finally about peculiarities of either

- a certain random process; or
- the pseudorandom number generator that I'm using; or
- other (specify!).

My question is: Which is it?  And what's actually going on?  I suspect it's the second alternative, but I'm not at all confident about that.

In the course of doing a bit of amateur cartography, I derived this little trigonometric relation:

If $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ is in the **right half** of the unit circle (in other words, $\cos\alpha>0$), and $$\tan\gamma=\dfrac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta},$$ and $\cos\gamma$ is also positive, then
$$\tan\dfrac\gamma2=\tan\dfrac\alpha2\cdot\tan\dfrac\beta2.$$
Numerical evidence bore out what I had derived, so now I should live happily ever after.

(And I was moderately intrigued by the resemblance to the simpler and more familiar tangent half-angle formula $\dfrac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta}=\tan\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$.)

But then I asked what happens in the **left half** of the circle, where the cosine is negative.  The answer turns out to be
$$
-\cot\frac\gamma2 = \tan\frac\alpha2\cdot\tan\frac\beta2.
$$
[But see the "later note" below.]

But instead of deriving this by massaging trigonometric identities I got lazy and did some "experimental mathematics".  Using R, I entered these commands:

```
a <- pi/180*(runif(1000)*(177 - 93) +93)
b <- pi/180*(runif(1000)*(177 - 93) +93) 
c <- atan( sin(a)*sin(b)/(cos(a)+cos(b) ))
u <- -1/(tan(a/2)*tan(b/2))
coefficients(lm(tan(c/2) ~ u))
```

(Intercept)           u  
         0           1

```
anova(lm(tan(c/2) ~ u))
```

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: tan(c/2) 
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq    F value    Pr(>F) 
u           1 29.222  29.222 2.1747e+34 < 2.2e-16 *** 

Residuals 998  0.000   0.000 

--- 

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1  
Warning message: 
In anova.lm(lm(tan(c/2) ~ u)) : 
ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable

```
plot(u,residuals(lm(tan(c/2) ~ u)))
```

So this puts $a$ and $b$ between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, or more precisely, between $93\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}$ and $177\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}$, and chooses 1000 such pairs $(a,b)$ independently, and they're uniformly distributed in that region.  Then it sets $c=\arctan(\sin a\sin b/(\cos a+\cos b))$, and $u=-1/(\tan a\tan b)$.  Then we look at coefficients from a simple linear regression of $\tan(c/2)$ on $u$, and the software reports $0$ for the intercept and $1$ for the slope.  An analysis of variance gives $0$ as the sum of squares of residuals, so it seems we have a perfect fit.

Finally, I plotted $u$ on the horizontal axis and the residuals on the vertical axis, and I got the following!  If real numbers rather than approximations could be used, they would of course all be $0$, so this is about rounding errors, but still I wouldn't expect to see a pattern like this.  I tried it a dozen or so times with pretty much the same result, and I tried it with the angles in the first quadrant and the identity that holds in that quadrant, with the same result again.

[image]

**LATER NOTE:** Well, haste makes waste, I guess.  I *should* have let $\gamma$ be the "other value of" the arctangent once I moved into the second quadrant, i.e. $\gamma=\arctan(\cdots\cdots\cdots)+\pi$ as soon as the argument to the arctangent function was more than $\pi/2$.  That way we still have the identity $\tan\frac\gamma2=\tan\frac\alpha2\cdot\tan\frac\beta2$.  However, this doesn't upset the main point of this question.  As I said, this already works in the *first* quadrant; I simply hadn't yet noticed it because at that point I was still doing things intelligently rather than numerically.

Comment: I see this got 6 views while I was still correcting some dumb typos.  Where should $\gamma$ appear without getting divided by $2$ and where should $\gamma/2$ appear.  I hope I've got all of them right by now, and I apologize for the distress that the incorrect versions must have caused.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for this, but it's presumably an artifact of using double precision.  A double precision number is a 52-bit approximation to something between 1 and 2 times a power of 2 (and a sign).  This means if $u$ is between $0.125$ and $0.25$, you'll get errors in multiples of $2^{-55}$, which is about $2.8 \cdot 10^{-17}$.  And that roughly matches the spacing here.  As $u$ increases by factors of $2$, the spacing should also double, which fits the graph (it changes when $u$ passes roughly $0.5$, $0.25$, and maybe $0.125$).

Comment: However, what I don't see how to explain is why the lines aren't perfectly flat (since double precision error should come in exact multiples in principle).  Am I missing something?

Comment: There should also be a good explanation of why the lines are most flat near $-0.2$ (but I don't see what it is offhand).

Comment: For the R-illiterate amongst us, could you confirm that this is what the plot is of? 

You're sampling random vectors of alphas and betas in the range 93deg to 177deg (converted to radians). 

Next you compute the vector of gammas = arctan ((sin alpha.sin beta)/(cos alpha+cos beta))

Finally you're plotting tan(gamma/2)+cot(alpha/2)cot(beta/2) vs -cot(alpha/2)cot(beta/2)?


Comment: @Anthony Quas: That seems to be right.

Comment: @ Henry: denormalized IEEE 754 floats can be much smaller than ulp(1).

Comment: http://perso.univ-perp.fr/mmartel/rangelab.html

Comment: @AnthonyQuas : The paragraph after the R code explains what was done in language that doesn't require any knowledge of R.  But it does use a bit of statistical terminology.  Basically I'm plotting two things agains each other that _should_ be equal---call them $x$ and $y$, and I'm looking at the amount by which $y$ differs from what it "should" be, and plotting that on the vertical axis and $x$ on the horizontal axis.  And the fact that the thing on the vertical axis is so small confirms that the trigonometric relation is correct.

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: You can certainly represent much smaller numbers, but if you subtract two numbers between $0.125$ and $0.25$, you'll get an integral multiple of $2^{-55}$.  When $u \approx -0.2$ in the plot, it's plotting the difference of two values in this range, and the answer is nearly zero.  The horizontal lines seem to be showing the multiples of $2^{-55}$ (at least they are pretty close to that numerically), but I'm confused by why they aren't exact.  Is there something more subtle going on here?  I'm clearly missing something, since I can't explain all the features of the graph.

Comment: You can get the same effect with seq(93,177,length.out=5000) instead of the random number generation step, right? That would point to purely numerical explanations and not pseudorandomization quirks

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you're right.  The advantage of randomness in this instance is that you'd want a $5000\times5000$ array in which every pair is realized.  Is easier to use stochastic independence and just pick the values of $a$ and $b$ separately and independently.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, if you do the same computation on Mathematica, you see something quite different (and very much like what @Henry Cohn predicted):

[image]

Comment: That's great!  Michael Hardy's picture shows more or less the same thing, except the horizontal lines are much fuzzier in the R version.  I'm still puzzled by why that should be.  I believe the Mathematica picture shows the true round-off error in double precision.  One possibility is that the R code is computing something slightly different; for example, the slope of the regression presumably is not 1 exactly, but just extremely close to 1.  However, it seems like this should introduce a gradual drift in the horizontal lines, not apparently random noise.  (Maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: Or R could be computing differently in another way, for example using standardized or studentized residuals, but I don't think it is for these commands.  I don't see how this could be a plotting issue, so it's got to have something to do with the underlying computation, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the results of a simpler computation (which in fact is what I did in Mathematica): plotting $\tan(\gamma/2)+\cot(\alpha/2)\cot(\beta/2)$ vs $-\cot(\alpha/2)\cot(\beta/2)$. I have some suspicions (without knowing anything about R) about what the lm and residuals functions are actually doing.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it's something to do with the "residuals" function in R.

If you do this

```
h <- fitted.values(lm(tan(c/2)~u))
plot(u,h-tan(c/2),ylim=c(-2e-16,2e-16),cex=0.1)
```

instead (with the previous code being the same) you get the following:
[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://i47.tinypic.com/dxd353.jpg)

Comment: Case closed (at least as far as I'm concerned)


Comment: It would still be nice to know what R is doing to get the messier pattern Michael Hardy observed, but it's really more of an R question.